# How should I make my 8ball command to answer a specific answer to a specific question in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

My code for 8ball is this:

```
async def klausimas(ctx):
    choices = ["Blah blah blah", "Blah blah blah"]
    ranquestion = random.choice(choices)
    
    await ctx.send(ranquestion)
```

How should I make it, so if someone for example asked this:
"/klausimas is *insert youtuber name* good?"
and the answer would be:
"Yes, they are good."
Could somebody help please? I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: 1. Use can use something referred to as a canned answer. Basically a dictionaries that has the exact question and answer pairs in there. 2. You can have a simple pattern matching where `is TOKEN good` phrase is processed and then you search your database for the `TOKEN`. 3. A more complicated chat bot which uses more advanced techniques such as NLP and performs search on a knowledge base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple implementation and brief explanation:

```py
async def klausimas(ctx, *, args=None):
    if args == None:
        choices = ["Blah blah blah", "Blah blah blah"]
        ranquestion = random.choice(choices)
    
        await ctx.send(ranquestion)
    else:
        if args.lower() == "is insert youtuber name good?":
            await ctx.send("Probably not.")
```

Adding `*, args=None` specifies that everything being sent after the command are optional command arguments.

You then want to set a default action for when users don't use any arguments.

`if args == None:`

You then compare the user input optional arguments against your string operand. It's helpful to convert the arguments and your operand to a specific case sensitivity.

`if args.lower() == "is insert youtuber name good?":`

There are more efficient ways to write this code, but I wanted to break it down for you simply and show you an easily extensible format, should you wish to add more e.g. ("is insert twitch streamer here good?")

Comment: Very good guide, sadly there is a problem. It appears that the random choice part doesn't work anymore

Comment: It most definitely should. Make sure you're importing the random module at the top of your script.

Comment: Still didn't work, no matter what I tried, it only works when I type the command, without arguments.

Comment: I just ran the exact script above (changing the strings within choices into unique strings instead of "Blah blah blah") and it worked as expected. Make sure to initialize your choices variable as a list and make sure there are no formatting or syntactical errors in your script